# multiple files with appendPartWithFileData

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to send multiple files in json structure like this :

```
files = {
    file1 = {
        nfo1 = "text 1 1",
        nfo2 = "text 1 2",
        data = <DATA>,
    },
    file2 = {
        nfo1 = "text 2 1",
        nfo2 = "text 2 2",
        data = <DATA>,
    },
}
```

I think i have to do something like this with AFHTTPSessionManager :

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"files":@{
       @"nfo1" = @"text 1 1",
       @"nfo2" = @"text 1 2",
   },
   @{
       @"nfo1" = @"text 2 1",
       @"nfo2" = @"text 2 2",
   }
};

[self POST:path parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData1 name:@"data" fileName:fileName1 mimeType:mimeType1];
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData2 name:@"data" fileName:fileName2 mimeType:mimeType2];

} success:nil failure:nil];
```

But i don't understand the way to identify data for file1 and for file2 using appendPartWithFileData !...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it :

```
[formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData1 name:@"files[file1[data]]" fileName:fileName1 mimeType:mimeType1];
[formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData2 name:@"files[file2[data]]" fileName:fileName2 mimeType:mimeType2];
```